# Would like help with LOGON Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've created a logon trigger in MS SQL that needs to check dm_exec_sessions for a login. This login is the user listed in the connection string and has owner right to the database. If the login is verified, I need it to update a specific table and send an email.

So far I've done just the following piece and it disabled my web site. The error I get is: "Logon failed for login 'dev' due to trigger execution. Changed database context to 'mydatabase'.  Changed language setting to us_english."

Any idea what I did wrong? Thanks,

Risho

```
CREATE TRIGGER TDY_Assets_Notification
ON ALL SERVER WITH EXECUTE AS 'dev'
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN

IF ORIGINAL_LOGIN()='dev' AND
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
            WHERE is_user_process = 1 AND
                original_login_name = 'dev') > 1

     UPDATE Assets_TDY 
        SET Suspense = 1, Warning = 1
        WHERE     (Date_Returned IS NULL) AND (GETDATE() >= DATEADD(day, 3, Date_Return))

END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try connecting with the [Dedicated Administrator Connection](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189595.aspx). That will give you an opportunity to disable the faulty logon trigger.

```
DISABLE TRIGGER [TDY_Assets_Notification] ON ALL SERVER
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your post. Why is the trigger "faulty"?

Risho.

Comment: Risho, I suspect the problem lies with the update statement. Try (1) Add a database and a schema prefix to the table name Assets_TDY e.g. Inventory.dbo.Assets_TDY. (2) Check that columns Suspense and Warning exist. (3) Check that user 'dev' has update permissions on the table.

Comment: Also check that columns Date_Returned and Date_Return exist on your table.